# Is application change required when new couchbase node added to cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, couchbase

I am using Node.js SDK to connect to a couchbase cluster. In Node.js docs they haven't specified how to pass multiple ips(of cluster nodes) while creating the cluster object but java docs shows it can accept array of IPs, is this functionality available in Node.js SDK too?

Also if this is how you connect to cluster with many nodes, whenever we add new nodes to cluster do we need to add its IP to the connection string and restart the application?

**PS** I am new to Couchbase and Node.js so please bear with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to place as many nodes as possible inside the connection string, so that in the event that one of the nodes is unavailable, the client would still be able to connect initially.

However to answer your original question, *no*, an application change/restart is not *required*. The client only needs to know about a *single* node that is part of the cluster, and will connect to that node and discover all the other nodes.

Both of these concepts will make sense when you consider how the client actually connects to the cluster.

#### Using a single node

1. The client connects to 10.4.4.1
2. The client requests the "Cluster Map" from 10.4.4.1. The cluster map contains information about the cluster itself, including the list of *all* nodes that art part of the cluster
3. The client connects to all the other nodes in the cluster map (this means 10.4.4.2, 10.4.4.3, and so on)

As Couchbase is a distributed system where all nodes know about all other nodes (and for this reason, you can log in to *any* node's administration console to administer the cluster), applications need only know about one initial node, and connecting to that node will inform them about all other nodes.

#### Passing multiple nodes

Let's say you've removed a single node from the cluster, `10.4.4.1`, so your cluster only has `10.4.4.2` and `10.4.4.3`. Since your application is configured to only connect to `10.4.4.1`, you would need to immediately reconfigure your code to connect to another node because the connection to 10.4.4.1 will fail. Since 10.4.4.1 is no longer part of the cluster it will not be able to provide information about other nodes.

If you've passed *all* the nodes to the cluster, the client would indeed try to still connect to 10.4.4.1, however once the client connection fails, it would proceed to try the next node (`10.4.4.2`) and successfully fetch a new configuration.

If you've added another node then nothing will fail - of course it's recommended that you *eventually* update your node list on your application, however it's not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is in the node.js SDK. Unfortunately I am not in a place where I can provide you a link.

When you add a new node to a Couchbase cluster, the topology change is updated on each client by sending out an updated cluster map. If you catch the cluster at that split second where the the cluster map has not been sent out yet, the SDK will get a "not my vbucket" error as well as the new cluster map at the same time. Regardless, your adding or removing a node should be transparent to your application.

Also, it is best practise to use at least 3 nodes of the cluster in the connection string or a DNS SRV record, then there is little chance of the client not bootstrapping and getting the initial cluster map.

I know this sound a bit odd, but it works very well.

Comment: As per http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/managing-connections.html this works: `var myCluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://10.4.4.1')` Do you mean to say I should do it like this `var myCluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://10.4.4.1,10.4.4.2,10.4.4.3')` and rest will be taken care by SDK itself?